# Propagate latest not None value to rest of items in izip_longest

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there is a way to have the default values of an "unmatched" item in a list set to the latest value in izip_longtest function.

*The problem*: i have a word which have a position on x, on y, and a rotation. Theses ones can be multiple and each letter of the word must have position/rotation.

More explicitely: i have two lists:

- the first one is itself a tuple (x, y, r) which are the positions and rotation that will match letters.
- the second is the character that will match the positions/rotation.

By example, if i have the word "HELLO" and `x = [1,2,3,4,5]`, `y = [6,7,8,9,10]` and `r = [11,12,13,14,15]`.

The 'H' letter will have `x = 1`, `y = 6`, `y = 11`
The last letter 'O' will have `x = 5`, `y = 10`, `r = 15`

But, if the word is "PROBLEM" and `x = [1]`, only the 'P' letter will match an x value and all the other letters will be set to `None` with `izip_longest`.

What i want is to "progagate" the latest or only one `x` to all the other letters. So, please, If you have any suggestion or solution, tell me. Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, `izip_longest` doesn't quite take you all the way there.  You can wrap it, however, and take it across the finish line.

```
def izip_longest_last_value(*args, **kwargs):
    last = (None,) * len(args)
    for x in izip_longest(*args, **kwargs):
        last = tuple(z if z is not None else last[y] for y,z in enumerate(x))
        yield last
```

`izip_longest` has a signature of *args, **kwargs, so we repeat that here.  We also support an arbitrary number of positional arguments, so you can izip 1, 2, or 46 different lists together.

We initialize last to be a tuple as long as the number of positional args.  Last will be updated to contain the values from the last iteration.

`for x in izip_longest()` is us grabbing the current value from izip_longest, the meat of the wrapper.

`last = tuple(...)` is us updating the last-tuple, and filling in either the current values from izip or the value from last if `izip_longest` returned a `None` for the space, indicating that it had been padded.

Answer (score 0):

Since the default `zip_longest` does not work for you here's a slightly smarter version:

```
import pprint
word = 'PROBLEM'

def zip_longest(*iterators):
    last = {}
    # Make a list of non-empty iterators
    non_empty = dict.fromkeys(range(len(iterators)))

    # Make sure it's an iterator, does no harm on iterators and helps
    # on lists
    iterators = map(iter, iterators)
    while non_empty:
        # Prepare the row
        row = []

        # Walk through the iterators in the given order
        for i, iterator in enumerate(iterators):
            # If there are still values, find the next
            if i in non_empty:
                try:
                    last[i] = iterator.next()
                except StopIteration:
                    # No items anymore, this one is empty
                    del non_empty[i]

            # Add the current (or last if it was already empty) value
            row.append(last.get(i))

        yield row
```

First/simple test:

```
x = [1]
y = [2]
pprint.pprint(list(zip_longest(word, x, y)))
[['P', 1, 2],
 ['R', 1, 2],
 ['O', 1, 2],
 ['B', 1, 2],
 ['L', 1, 2],
 ['E', 1, 2],
 ['M', 1, 2],
 ['M', 1, 2]]
```

Slightly more complicated:

```
x = range(3)
y = range(6)
pprint.pprint(list(zip_longest(word, x, y)))
[['P', 0, 0],
 ['R', 1, 1],
 ['O', 2, 2],
 ['B', 2, 3],
 ['L', 2, 4],
 ['E', 2, 5],
 ['M', 2, 5],
 ['M', 2, 5]]
```

With other longer ranges:

```
x = range(10)
y = range(5)
pprint.pprint(list(zip_longest(word, x, y)))

[['P', 0, 0],
 ['R', 1, 1],
 ['O', 2, 2],
 ['B', 3, 3],
 ['L', 4, 4],
 ['E', 5, 4],
 ['M', 6, 4],
 ['M', 7, 4],
 ['M', 8, 4],
 ['M', 9, 4],
 ['M', 9, 4]]
```

For completeness:

```
x = []
y = []
pprint.pprint(list(zip_longest(word, x, y)))

[['P', None, None],
 ['R', None, None],
 ['O', None, None],
 ['B', None, None],
 ['L', None, None],
 ['E', None, None],
 ['M', None, None],
 ['M', None, None]]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But it only works if i have only one stuff to "unpack". If i have y and r in the same case, i can't use this method anymore ... I mean, i can't to y[-1] and r[-1] in the same fillvalue to fill the matching attribute

Answer (score 0):

You will probably require your own custom *zip* iterator. Mostly based on `izip_longest` but with some memory of the last `not None` value.

There is probably room for improvement, but here is the spirit:

```
import itertools

def myzip(it1, it2):
    last1 = None
    last2 = None
    for i in itertools.izip_longest(it1, it2):
        if i[0] is not None:
            last1 = i[0]
        if i[1] is not None:
            last2 = i[1]
        yield((last1, last2))
```

And here is the "test case":

```
>>> lst1 = ('a', 'b')
>>> lst2 = (1,2,3,4,5)

>>> print list(myzip(lst1, lst2))
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3), ('b', 4), ('b', 5)]

>>> print list(myzip(lst2, lst1))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'b'), (5, 'b')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.cycle()` for the shorter input and do *not* use `izip_longest()`:

```
from itertools import cycle, izip

izip(word, cycle(x), cycle(y), cycle(r))
```

Now `x`, `y` and `r` will be cycled through to match up with the rest of the characters in `word`:

```
>>> list(zip(word, cycle(x), cycle(y), cycle(r)))
[('P', 1, 6, 11), ('R', 2, 7, 12), ('O', 3, 8, 13), ('B', 4, 9, 14), ('L', 5, 10, 15), ('E', 1, 6, 11), ('M', 2, 7, 12)]
```